# SharpeRatio in PortfolioAnalytics package in R

Tags: r, performanceanalytics

I'm trying to calculate the sharpRatio of a return series using the package PerformanceAnalytics in R.
my data looks as follows:

```
head(simpleRet)
  2006-01-02   2006-01-03   2006-01-04   2006-01-05   2006-01-06   2006-01-09 
 0.000000000  0.002495244  0.001018385 -0.001903177  0.002254347  0.002000196
```

and is of class zoo.
I'mm using the code :

```
library("PerformanceAnalytics")
SharpeRatio(simpleRet, Rf = 0.05, p = 0.95, FUN = "StdDev", weights = NULL, annualize = TRUE)
print(YY)
```

but I get the following error message:

```
Error in FUNCT(R = R, p = p, ... = ..., invert = FALSE) : 
  'x' needs to be timeBased or xtsible, or scale must be specified.
```

any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can help.

```
sr <- SharpeRatio(simpleRet, Rf = 0.05, p = 0.95, FUN = "StdDev", scale=252)
```

*weights* and *annualize* arguments have default values so no need to specify them. Missing parameter was *scale*.  Here's scale argument info:

```
scale   
number of periods in a year (daily scale = 252, monthly scale = 12, quarterly scale = 4)
```